# CoreLocation can't use with Estimotes Beacon

Tags: swift2, core-location, ibeacon, estimote

I build a app with Estimotes indoor Location ,any I use CoreLocation to find our beacon, and my app will change label.text. App can run,but didn't work ,label.text can't change.

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("location", ofType: "json")
    do {
    let content = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let locationSetup = ESTLocationBuilder.parseFromJSON(content)

    //set up delegate
    manager.delegate = self
    locationManager.delegate = self  
 if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() !=  CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
}
  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons:[CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion){

    let knownBeacons = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.Unknown }
    if (knownBeacons.count > 0){
        let closestBeacon = knownBeacons[0] as CLBeacon
        if(closestBeacon.minor.integerValue == 41016)
        {
            self.snow.text = "find"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding NSLog statements inside didRangeBeacons:inRegion: and inside your two if statements.  Which log lines get printed?

Comment: I add NSLog in code ,    if (knownBeacons.count > 0){  NSLog("find beacon")   and   if(closestBeacon.minor.integerValue == 41016){ NSLog("catch") }      But Output can't print anything ,  I don't know why this function can't run.

Comment: Where in code do you initialize `locationManager`?  I do not see it.  Is it possibly nil?

Comment: __let locationManger = CLLocationManager()__ ,I have declared this in the class

Answer (score 0):

**First thing to try:**

I would move the initialization of `locationManger = CLLocationManager()` outside the class instance declaration and inside `viewDidLoad`.    I have seen problems initializing the location manager during object construction.

Comment: Thank you , I found my problem. I forget to allow corelocaiotn when I testing App ,so I can't use